Overwrite syntax highlighting for comments depending on the number of comment symbols
I'm a new user to emacs so i'm sorry if this has a simple answer.
This is very related to this issue : Syntax highlighting for comments starting with specific sequence of characters
I'm trying to change the comments color depending if there is # or ## or ##! at the start. But similarly in other major mode like lisp with ; ;; and ;;!
My first approach was to use the comment of Stefan, with a function that would use the return of font-lock-syntactic-face-function to define the color of the line. And then hooked it to after-change-major-mode-hook.
While this would indeed change the color of the comments I lost all other syntax highlighting.
I wonder if it was possible to modify any comments line face overriding only that in package that do syntax-highlighting.
Thanks

Please don't post a duplicate question just because the original question doesn't have an answer that satisfies you. Thx.

You are right, i'm sorry. Not used to stack echange :)
I'll add a solution I managed to do on the original post
